# Proof verification for Lebesgue's number lemma

Tags: general-topology, analysis, solution-verification

Lebesgue's number lemma: Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and $\{U_j\}_{j\in J}$ be an open cover of $X$. Then there exist a $\delta>0$ such that for each set $A \subset X$ with diameter smaller then $\delta$ there is at least one $U_j$ with $A \subset U_j$.

My Proof: Since $X$ is compact we can choose a finite subcover $U_{j_1}, \dots, U_{j_n}$. Now define a new open cover :For $x \in X$ there exists $i=1,\dots,n$ such that $x \in U_{j_i}$ and $\epsilon_x >0$ such that $\{y \in X: d(x,y)<\epsilon_x\}\subset U_{j_i}$. Then $\{y \in X: d(x,y)<\frac{\epsilon_x}{2}\}_{x \in X} $ is an open cover of $X$ and we again have a finite subcover
$\{y \in X: d(x_1,y)<\frac{\epsilon_{x_1}}{2}\}, \dots, \{y \in X: d(x_k,y)<\frac{\epsilon_{x_k}}{2}\}$.

Define the Lebesgue number $\delta:=\min_{i=1, \dots,k}\; \frac{\epsilon_{x_i}}{2} $ as the smallest of all epsilons of the finite subcover.

If we now choose $x,y \in A \subset X \text{ with } diam(A)<\delta$ then $x \in \{z \in X: d(x_i,z)<\frac{\epsilon_{x_i}}{2}\}$ for an $i=1,\dots,k$ and since $d(x_i,y)\leq d(x,x_i)+d(x,y)< \frac{\epsilon_{x_i}}{2}+ \delta\leq \epsilon_{x_i}$ it follows that $y \in \{z \in X: d(x_i,z)<\epsilon_{x_i}\}$ and we can conclude that $A \subset U_{j_l} $ for that $U_{j_l}$ that contains $\{z \in X: d(x_i,z)<\epsilon_{x_i}\}$.

Is this Proof correct?